# how to see phonegap javascript log messages on xcode console

Tags: javascript, cordova, logging

I am trying to develop a basic hello world application with phonegap on Xcode. But i can not see the log messages on Xcode console. I have tried *console.log* and *debug.log* but they did not worked for me?

How can i see javascript log messages on xcode console?

Answer (score 27):

In Phonegap 3.0 you have to add a plugin for console.log to work in the xcode console.

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git
```

More info: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

Comment: Note, that you need to run it from your project folder and have Git for Mac installed (from here: http://git-scm.com/download/mac).

Comment: I believe that most of the people using **Phonegap** have **Git** installed anyway. On my machine ```cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git``` *(Cordova 3.4.0)*

Comment: on ``https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console/blob/master/doc/index.md`` they say: ``cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console`` which did the job for me!

Answer (score 10):

1. On your real iDevice or in iOS simulator go to `Settings > Safari > Advanced` and turn on `Web Inspector`.
2. Desktop Safari:  `Safari > Preferences > Advanced` and select the `Show develop menu in menu bar` checkbox.
3. Now that you have either iOS Simulator open or your iDevice connected to your mac start using web inspector on your website: On your mac, open Safari and go to `Develop`

Comment: Much more helpful than just console messages, indeed. This also allows you to manipulate the DOM for example. See my answer [Configuring iOS and Xcode for remote debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15818612/1548776) for more detailed instructions on setup.

Comment: This isn't useful if your goal is to see javascript log messages on xcode console.

Comment: Much easier and a better way to accomplish what OP wants without relying in a plugin.

Answer (score 8):

Phonegap has a pretty good blog post about this [here](http://phonegap.com/2011/05/18/debugging-phonegap-javascript/).

One of the things they mention includes [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) which I personally use a decent amount. You just post your JS code there and it'll scan for errors and good styling. I also suggest trying to put t the code in a simple html file and run it on the browser. Anything that might seem phone-related, just get rid of it. Its nice to sandbox your javascript on the browser side and then use things like Firebug or Chrome's debugger. (Also I'm sure `console.log()` will work there :D)

I've also seen a lot of people mention, including in the blog post, about [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) so that is something worth checking out.

Other relevant questions that might help:

[Phonegap - Javascript debugging in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827213/phonegap-javascript-debugging-in-xcode)

[iOS PhoneGap debug Workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207001/ios-phonegap-debug-workflow)

[How to see the javascript errors of PhoneGap app in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022152/how-to-see-the-javascript-errors-of-phonegap-app-in-xcode)

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Found this recently: [Debugging in Phonegap](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap)

Answer (score 4):

`console.log("msg here: "+var);` should work.
It will come out as `...[INFO] msg here: hi!` (after the date, time, app, etc.).

To view the messages go to View > Debug Area > Activate Console (or shift+cmd+C)

Comment: Uh, why not... that's exactly where the log messages will appear

Comment: In which program (XCode, Safari?) the command "View > Debug Area > Activate Console (or shift+cmd+C)" should be executed?

Answer (score 2):

As @NickBreen said, you must add the right plugin, but we also needed to wait for the `deviceready` event to fire before the console displayed log statements.

Answer (score 2):

In later versions of phonegap/cordova, to add the debug console plugin in your project:

**cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console**

Comment: In later versions of phonegap/cordova, this is: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just needed to comment the following lines in the cordova.js :

> if(typeof window.console === "undefined") {
>       window.console = {
>           log:function(){}
>       };

Answer (score 0):

1. [Add the Debug console plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface)
2. Add a console.log message in onDeviceReady in the sample phonegap code or code that runs after that.

Important: console messages are displayed after the 'deviceready' event. Console.log **will not** generate message before that.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The following or a similar error message occurs when adding the console plugin to the ios platform (or after reinstalling) via Command-line Interface:

> **"CDVPlugin class CDVLogger (pluginName: Console) does not exist."**

**Solution**

Open your Xcode project and go to the tab "Build Phases". Now open the drop-down named "Compile Sources". Click on the "+" sign at the end of the list and add "CDVLogger.m" or any other missing source.

Answer (score -1):

```
confirm("msg here: "+var);
```

or

```
console.log("msg here: "+var);
```

Comment: Neither will send phonegap javascript log messages to the xcode console.