# Can't use phonegap methods for iOS in xcode

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova

I do get it to read html and use regular js and jQuery methods, but it gives me nothing when I try to use [these commands](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/index.html).

These are before my script:

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
```

Doing this:

```
var text = "grewrfar";
document.write(text);
```

...works fine, while for instance:

```
var text = device.uuid;
document.write(text);
```

...does not.

Also, I saw some people using navigator before the commands:

```
var text = navigator.device.uuid;
document.write(text);
```

This didn't work either.

How do I get it to work? Googling does not get me near a discussion about this, so I'm guessing I'm doing something really stupid. Just a nudge in a direction to look would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using calling this code after onDeviceReady fires?

Comment: Umm.. nope. Let me give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access Phonegap's API before the [onDeviceReady](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#deviceready) event is being fired.

Add this to your JS -

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {    //This will fire only when the Phonegap lib is fully loaded
   console.log(device.uuid);
}
```

Comment: Although, actually now the console.logs don't show up. document.write works fine and shows in the app, but console.log doesn't show up anywhere. Nor where these things show up: "Simulator","uuid":"62e0ca2cdd1850a58d7004f9d27e252900000000","platform":"iPhone Simulator","gap":"1.5.0","version":"6.1","connection":{"type":"wifi"}};". Any idea?

Comment: Are you testing this on a simulator?

Comment: Yes (comment requires more letters than 3)

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, check the DDMS perspective. Is it not showing up there?

Comment: Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357568/how-to-see-phonegap-javascript-log-messages-on-xcode-console

Answer (score 1):

Try this  Example..

```
   // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('result');

        element.innerHTML = 'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid ;
    }
```

under Body Tag..

```
<p id="result">Loading device properties...</p>
```